# Do followers of Lyotard consider modernism deconstructive?

Tags: postmodernism, deconstruction, modernism

Do followers of Lyotard consider modernism deconstructive? I ask only because I've read that

> Furthermore, says Lyotard, a work can become modern only if it is
>   first postmodern, for postmodernism is not modernism at its end but in
>   its nascent state, that is, at the moment it attempts to present the
>   unpresentable, “and this state is constant” (Lyotard 1984 [1979], 79).
>   The postmodern, then, is a repetition of the modern as the “new,” and
>   this means the ever-new demand for another repetition.

And I wonder what that has got to with 'deconstruction'?

Comment: You could say postmodernism is the deconstruction of modernism, the reiteration of the questioning and critiqueing of reason that characterized early stages of modernism, before complacency settled in, see [Postmodernism and the Deconstruction of Modernism by Ferraris and Taraboletti](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1511383).

Comment: i had seen the [name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maurizio_Ferraris) but not his movement. @Conifold thanks

Answer (score 1):

The point he is making is analogous to this: Once you have the notion of culture, it means you are already multicultural. Prior to the concept of culture, there is yourself, and the barbarians or others. Mihima speaks of the Americans twice forcing the Japanese to look at themselves in the American mirror. The Japanese ceased to be a "mono-culture" and became one culture among many. This effects also their past, or, their current view of their history. Now it is grasped that history can be understood under a new mirror. The deconstruction of it is also gleamed in the past. It is now understood that this re-writing was always happening. It has simply come to more clear consciousness.